# APACHE 2 DNS: DNS for mail server

Tags: server, apache2, dns, mail

I am trying to configure my own mail server.
My domain name is: exemple.net

I've created a sub-domaine (a virtual host an apache2): mail.exemple.net 
my hostname is: server01 (the name of the server I get using Ubuntu hostname command line)

I only have one server with several virtual host: exemple.net (website) – mail.exemple.net (mail).

my record for the zone file for the doamin exemple.net should be:

```
mail 10800 IN A 123.123.123.123
@ 10800 IN MX 10 server01.mail.exemple.net.
```

So my zone is:

```
@ 10800 IN A 123.123.123.123
mail 10800 IN A 123.123.123.123
server01 10800 IN A 123.123.123.123
www 10800 IN A 123.123.123.123
@ 10800 IN MX 10 server01.mail.exemple.net.
```

or

```
mail 10800 IN A 123.123.123.123
@ 10800 IN MX 10 mail.exemple.net.
```

So my zone is:

```
@ 10800 IN A 123.123.123.123
mail 10800 IN A 123.123.123.123
server01 10800 IN A 123.123.123.123
www 10800 IN A 123.123.123.123
@ 10800 IN MX 10 mail.exemple.net.
```

Thanks in advance for your help; it is very much appreciated 
Very best regards